# Get user-added parameter from Firebase Dynamic Link iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I have Firebase Dynamic Link with custom parameter `id`

`https://someapp.page.link/Hnsd?id=0101`

How can I get `id` parameter in app?

Or how is it possible to get this url `https://someapp.page.link/Hnsd?id=0101` in app?

Answer (score 0):

[url encode](https://www.urlencoder.org/) `id=0101`

`https://someapp.page.link/Hnsd?id=0101` to `https://someapp.page.link/Hnsd?id%3D0101` convert

this worked for me

Answer (score -1):

You can handle the received deep link in App delegate like this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        
        guard let incomingUrl = userActivity.webpageURL else { return false }

        let handled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingUrl) { (dynamicLink, error) in

            if let url = dynamicLink?.url{
                let id= url["id"]
                print(id) //Prints 0101
            }
        }
        return handled
    }
```